# Logging of State of the Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting the state to an empty array, then calling a function to update the state of the component.  When I log the state of the function, I am getting the empty array and the updated array at the same time.

Any reason why this is happening and how to only log the updated state.

Following is my code:

```
class App extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      videos: [],
    };
    YTSearch({ key: API_Keys, term: 'USA Top40' }, (videos) => {
      this.setState({ videos });
    });
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
          {console.log(this.state)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the console.log

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, when I do console.log(this.state), within the constructor method, it is not even recording the updated state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't return `console.log` in `render` method!

It's better your code should be:

```
class App extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { videos: [] };
  } 
  componentDidMount() {
    YTSearch({ key: API_Keys, term: 'USA Top40' }, (videos) => {
      this.setState({ videos });
    });
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { videos } = this.state;
    if(prevState.videos !== videos) {
      console.log(videos);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, you can place `console.log` outside of return:

```
render() {
  console.log(this.state);
  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: setState({}) is an async process more like a batch process that
>   runs asynchronously and doesn't block your UI. So you might not see
>   the updated results in the console right after you change the state.

I agree with @souroush's answer as it is recommended way of doing things. But one way to achieve what you're trying to do is make a function and console logging the state into it

```
     logState = () =>{ 
           console.log("State" , this.state) 
      }

     render() {   
       return (
           <div>
              <SearchBar />
              {this.logState()}
           </div> 
        )}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this too (apart from Souroush's answer), but it threw an error.